# Testing tool for TCP/IP communication

Tags: objective-c, macos, ipad

I am creating an iPad app, which has to communicate with a WiFi enable device using TCP/IP protocol. I have the API sets of the device for communication. Now what i want is i would like to see whether the device is responding to the requests send via TCP/IP. Please suggest a good tool for MAC OS, where i can simulate the WiFi communication and get the response messages from the device.

Thanking you guys in advance

Comment: An interesting kickstarter project: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1002798642/tcp-ip-bouncer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question you may use telnet. With telnet you can establish a TCP connection with the device and communicate with it, sending and receiving messages.

Comment: I downloaded a telnet client but i cannot communicate with the device. Sorry i missed out an important thing. I know only the ip of the device, there is no port number mentioned any where in the device. Please help me out..

Comment: The app on the device is a client or a server?

Comment: Its an analytical tool its has a Server app.

Comment: If it's a server app it needs to have a constant listening port (if it's not constant, reach the server will become a problem). Post the code where you create the server.

Answer (score 2):

I have just started to use MAC OSX recently and I also have the same question as yours.
Luckily I have found a good tool that you can try:
https://packetsender.com/

It's multiplatform, support both TCP and UDP client/server.